# foreign libraries in a shared library

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, shared

I've written a c++ shared library that is based on several other libraries. 
Now when using the library I get a lot of undefined references concerning the functions of the 'foreign' libraries. Compiling and linking works fine if i explicitly add the 'foreign' libs to the g++ command. Is there away to cope with that so that the library user does not have to link against the 'foreign' libraries manually?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want users of your shared-library having to declare all the link-time dependencies of your library, you can inform the linker already of those dependencies when building the shared-library itself.

In a Makefile, this would look like this:

```
mylib.so:
    g++ -o mylib.so $OBJS -llib1 -llib2 -llib3
```

Then the users of `mylib.so` don't need to specify `lib1`, `lib2` or `lib3`, but they would still need to be available (in the right version) for the program to be able to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude all external datatypes and functions from your published (exported) interface. It means, for GCC, you can use `-fvisibility=hidden` to hide all implementation details, so, export only your parts with [**attribute** ((dllexport)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). Pimpl idiom (aka [Opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)) helps you with removing dependencies from published headers.
Quick example below:

```
#include<memory>    

#if EXPORT_DLL
   #define DLL_PREFIX __attribute__ ((dllexport))
#else
   #define DLL_PREFIX __attribute__ ((dllimport))
#endif 

class XImpl;

class DLL_PREFIX X {
//...
private:
   std::unique_ptr<XImpl> impl_;
}
```

Define and implement your `XImpl` in another header/source and that's all. No link dependency from other libs, only from yours. But runtime dependency still exists!

Comment: thanks for your response, but I dont understand it compeletly. Assuming the interface class for my library is iface.hpp and the implementation is in iface.cpp (in this file calls to the external libraries occur). How would i implement your solution?

Comment: Your iface.hpp would contain `X` definition and forward declaration of `XImpl`(as I mentioned erarlier) and iface.cpp could contain `XImpl` definition OR include external header with it, so there you can init and `impl_` field and forward all methods through it.

For example, if you X contains some method `void f()` than you should add similar method to XImpl and call it in iface.cpp while implementing `f()` from interface class to do actual work.

Comment: okay, so I write a new class forwarding all calls to the iface class. But some function calls in iface have parameters that are of a type provided by a foreign language. Hence I'll have to include the related headers. And then i'm at the same point?

Comment: You can redefine your published interface to accept only basic, standard types or provide your own. So, in iface.cpp you are free to construct any other, provided by 3rdparty libraries since that parts of code are hidden from library user. You also can forward declare needed external types and pass arguments by pointers or references! But think deeper, library user can't construct/access interface their interface without external libraries, external linker dependencies.